# Why the background of a UIButton is not hidden when its isHidden Property is set to true?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am an IOS and swift newbie. I tried to hide buttons using the isHidden property. Their titles were gone but their backgrounds remained. Fromt the info I got on the internet, the whole button view should have gone. Why did this happen?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var storyTextView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
    var storyIndex: Int = 0
    var storys = QuestionBank().list


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateUI(index: 0)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if storyIndex == 0{
            if (sender.tag == 1) {
                updateUI(index: 2)
            } else {
                updateUI(index: 1)
            }
        } else if storyIndex == 1 {
            if (sender.tag == 1) {
                updateUI(index: 2)
            } else {
                updateUI(index: 3)
            }
        } else if storyIndex == 2 {
            if (sender.tag == 1) {
                updateUI(index: 5)
            } else {
                updateUI(index: 4)
            }
        }
    }

    func updateUI(index: Int, showButton: Bool = true) {
        storyIndex = index
        storyTextView.text = storys[index].question
        print(index)

        if (showButton) {
            button1.setTitle(storys[index].answer1, for: .normal)
            button2.setTitle(storys[index].answer2, for: .normal)
        } else {
            button1.isHidden = true
            button2.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: As per the code shared, you are not set the hidden property for those two buttons since if case executed all the time, So please hardcode the title values instead of storys[index].answer then check again and share the screenshots.

Comment: Your function declaration implies that your `showButton` is optional, and if it is not set, then it will always be `true`. That's why it never gets hidden. Check your code and you will see that you never set the `showButton`, and thus, he was always `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the condition with calling isHidden = false not called at all, but the setting story answer works but answer is string for some reasons and in fact you set an empty string in the button title

Try to put print where you set the title and make sure that the answer text is not empty
and don’t forget to set isHidden false when you want to show the button it’s important

```
    if showButton {
        button1.isHidden = false
        button2.isHidden = false
        button1.setTitle(storys[index].answer1, for: .normal)
        button2.setTitle(storys[index].answer2, for: .normal)
    } else {
        button1.isHidden = true
        button2.isHidden = true
    }
```

In a pinch, set breakpoints to see that condition calls

Answer (score 0):

The `showButton` property is true always, so the else case won't execute.
You need to pass the value for that argument, if you don't pass the value it will be true (Because it's a default argument). In your case the if condition is executing always and when there is no value for answer1 and answer2, the title will be set to empty.

Answer (score 0):

You will always hit the first `if` here, and it looks like you don't set `isHidden` to false.

If you don't set it back to false then you wont ever show your button after it has been hidden for the first time.

I would check your question array is being read properly by debugging your application as that seems to be more of your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

According to your provided code, the optional parameter *showButton* properties in updateUI function never been assigned to false.

Also The reason of the title hidden on the UIbutton is because the List *storys* is never assigned with any value (according to your code).
You may amend the showButton to false in viewDidLoad to test the hidden function is working.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateUI(index: 0: false)
}
```